# tomcat webapp with dbcp pooling - pool threads are free, but http-bio threads cannot acquaore it

Tags: tomcat, connection-pooling, connection-leaks, jdbc-pool

dear all!

I have a bit strange situation when sometimes (it's not repeat easily) my Tomcat web application fails in strange situation (if i correctly interpred thread dumps).
I have 100 pool threads in tomcat context pooling configuration, and all my 100 threads in thread-dump looks like:

```
"pool-1-thread-100" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1024293000 nid=0x6da0 waiting on condition [0x00007f0ffb5b4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c5f17298> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

AFAIK it means that it's free and ok
But all my http threads look like

```
"http-bio-8181-exec-51" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f102002f000 nid=0x6dd4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f0ffa1e1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1115)
    - locked <0x00000000c1123330> (a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1749)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1726)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2397)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2222)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:257)
    at ru.croc.wli.wliClientSynch.daoext.SystemUserDaoExtendedImpl.findWithoutDomain(SystemUserDaoExtendedImpl.java:39)
    at ru.croc.wli.wliLogic.impl.UserFacadeImpl.findWithoutDomain(UserFacadeImpl.java:197)
    at ru.croc.wli.wliClientSynch.helper.UserHelper.getCurrentUser(UserHelper.java:19)
    at ru.croc.wli.wliClientSynch.cas.WLIUserDetailService.loadUserDetails(WLIUserDetailService.java:31)
    at ru.croc.wli.wliClientSynch.cas.WLIUserDetailService.loadUserDetails(WLIUserDetailService.java:21)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:180)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    - locked <0x00000000c1123a68> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

and AFAIK it means it fails to retreive connection from the pool.
Am i right in my suggestions and why so strange behavior from pool?

Comment: Now sure if this is related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879706/why-does-my-tomcat-only-open-8-jdbc-connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correct. pool-1-thread-100 and similar has nothing to do with the state of the database connections in the connection pool. It looks like you have a connection leak in your application.