# Why does my Tomcat only open 8 JDBC connections

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat8

When setting up the database connections in Tomcat 8, for some reason Tomcat is not following what I configured in the context.xml, with as result that I run out of connections, leading to resource contentions at the application server side (BLOCKED/WAITING threads). I always have 8 connections (show processlist in mariadb/mysql) after the pool initializes. My configuration states a minimum of 10 connections and a maximum of 100 connections.

I tested different configurations, but this does not make any difference at all, which is strange at least. The context.xml is used else it would not be able to connect to the database at all.

What is happening here? Why only 8 connections?

Software versions:
- MySQL JDBC driver: Latest (5.1.35) 
- Java 1.8.0_05

I also observed with with my previous setup: Tomcat 7, Java 1.7, older MySQL JDBC drivers, MySQL instead of MariaDB. So the problem does not seem directly version related.

Show processlist output (Showing the 8 processes):

```
| Id    | User          | Host          | db                | Command | Time | State     | Info            | Progress |                                                                     
+-------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+-----------+-----------------+----------+
| 71153 | root          | localhost     | vnitdatacollector | Query   |    0 | init      | show processlist|    0.000 |                                                                     
| 73473 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58585 | vnitdatacollector | Sleep   |    0 |           | NULL            |    0.000 |                                                                     
| 73474 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58586 | vnitdatacollector | Sleep   |    0 |           | NULL            |    0.000 |                                                                     
| 73482 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58606 | vnitdatacollector | Query   |    0 | update    | INSERT INTO ... |    0.000 |
| 73483 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58607 | vnitdatacollector | Sleep   |    0 |           | NULL            |    0.000 |                                                                     
| 73485 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58618 | vnitdatacollector | Query   |    0 | query end | INSERT INTO ... |    0.000 |
| 73487 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58624 | vnitdatacollector | Sleep   |    0 |           | NULL            |    0.000 |                                                                     
| 73488 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58634 | vnitdatacollector | Sleep   |    0 |           | NULL            |    0.000 |                                                                     
| 73489 | vnit_datacoll | virt005:58637 | vnitdatacollector | Query   |    7 | update    | INSERT INTO ... |    0.000 |
+-------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+-----------+-----------------+----------+
```

I have the following context.xml configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource 
    name="jdbc/dbaccess" 
    auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" 
    maxIdle="100"
    minIdle="10"
    maxWait="1000"
    initialSize="10"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="5000"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000" 
    testWhileIdle="true"
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
    logAbandoned="true"
    username="some_user" 
    password="{the password}" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/dbaccess?useFastDateParsing=false&amp;jdbcCompliantTruncation=false"
  />
  <Resource
    name="mail/emailconnection"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.mail.Session"
    mail.smtp.host="some.stmp.server"
  />             
</Context>
```

The following thread issue then shows up after a (short) period:

```
"Thread-495" #517 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f678c040800 nid=0x1642 waiting on condition [0x00007f67848f4000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f21933f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:439)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    at com.hipersonik.util.ServiceLocator.getConnection(ServiceLocator.java:32)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from "[Tomcat Expert: Configuring jdbc-pool for high-concurrency](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency)":

> When Tomcat reads the `type="javax.sql.DataSource"` it will automatically configure its repackaged DBCP, unless you specify a different factory. The factory object is what creates and configures the connection pool itself.

It turns out that DBCP package just ignores a series of settings. Adding the following line to the `context.xml` resource configuration, gets better response in the database:

```xml
<Resource 
 ....
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
 ....
/>
```

Show processlist in mysql then immediately shows the desired behaviour.

Comment: That link is now gone, but it was recorded by the wayback machine:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180521112213/http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency

Answer (score 6):

By default (ie if not setting the factory setting of your ressource), tomcat7 uses commons dbcp1.

Tomcat also provides an alternate pool implementation (the tomcat jdbc connection pool) that you can use by setting  factory=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory on your ressource

Tomcat8 uses commons dbcp2 by default, which has different names for some very important configuration parameters ( see https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Database_Connection_Pooling ) as dbcp1 (and the tomcat jdbc connection pool, because it mostly has the same configuration options as commons dbcp1).

So basically, before tomcat8, you didn't have to pay attention to which connection pool you were using because of the configuration compatibilty. With tomcat8, you have to pay attention.

Tomcat connection pool documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Default commons dbcp2 documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources

Comment: This response is more clear. In the question the  maxActive="100" arg is ignored as, from the Tomcat docs (https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Database_Connection_Pooling):
"The maxActive configuration option has been renamed to maxTotal"

In similar cases in catalina logs you should see:
WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = myDataSource Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "100" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.