# Getting CommunicationsException after some (8) hours idle time on Apache Tomcat + MySQL

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, database-connection

I am newbie in J2EE.

I write a J2EE web application on eclipse and moved it to my Ubuntu 16.06 in which I have installed Apache Tomcat 8 and MySQL 5.7 (and I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar).

I repeatedly get the following error after some (8) hours idle time:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1182)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4035)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4004)
    .
    .
    .
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 55,475,050 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 55,475,050 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2509)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:82)
    at aut.ceit.isec.requestHandler.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:51)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3728)
    ... 40 more
```

I read many similar posts on SO about this issue but I was unable to solve my problem.

My context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/db" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" username="root" password="xxxxxx"
    autoReconnect="true" defaultAutoCommit="true" validationQuery="select 1+1"
    testOnBorrow="true" />
</Context>
```

I also get following strange INFO on my catalina.out file (autoReconnect="true" was recommended by the Tomcat in error log!!!):

```
Jun 28, 2017 2:20:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
INFO: Name = db Ignoring unknown property: value of "true" for "autoReconnect" property
```

Should I configure something like "wait_timeout" on MySQL?

.

P.S. Since my Tomcat and MySQL are on the same server, I think firewall might not be an issue.

Comment: You need a keep alive, and you might want to replace your tomcat drivers since the default one is lacking some functionalities (which can also result in this issue: The keep alive does not seem to be used as well as the reconnect failing: The reconnect option should have prevented this error).

Comment: Pardon me for my basic question: what is tomcat driver? Is it the catalina.jar? With which file should I replace it? Please guide me.

Comment: Please help me! I am stuck on this problem for 2 weeks!!!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879706/why-does-my-tomcat-only-open-8-jdbc-connections/30879793#30879793 for a working connection pool (also apply the answer).