# Hive metastore service failed with a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, hive, metastore

Here is the hive metastore error log, I have tried `autoReconnect=true` in JDBC url, it takes no effect. Do you have any idea about it?

```
17/08/20 00:24:06 [pool-3-thread-9487]: ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: Retrying HMSHandler after 5000 ms (attempt 2 of 10) with error: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getDataStoreConnection(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.trySetAnsiQuotesForMysql(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_tables(HiveMetaStore.java:2835)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.get_tables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_tables.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_tables.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8086)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:877)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3598)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.isReadOnly(ConnectionHandle.java:867)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:422)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getXAResource(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:378)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:328)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:94)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getNucleusConnection(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1357)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getDataStoreConnection(JDOPersistenceManager.java:2245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.trySetAnsiQuotesForMysql(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_tables(HiveMetaStore.java:2835)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.get_tables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_tables.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_tables.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8086)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:48)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,412,672 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,412,672 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'interactive_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3652)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2460)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2505)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1370)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3623)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3634)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: You will ahve to provide more information for a good answer and less exception (relevant parts to start with). What is your configuration you use (Code + relevant XML, not too much: Nobody will be able to read all of it). Just a hint on the MySQL driver behavior in combination with Java: Autoreconnect seems to work only with certain jars. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879706/why-does-my-tomcat-only-open-8-jdbc-connections for a similar behavior in which connection settings are ignored.

Comment: Hive version is 0.13.1, it use a bonecp connection pool by default, mysql version is 5.6,  in hive-site.xml the  `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` is `jdbc:mysql://host:port/hive_meta?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;interactiveClient=true`, besides, the mysql account is read-only

Comment: I have found a similar question, but there's not any answers: [link](http://stackmirror.cn/page/s1gq7vbye6gp)

Comment: I would try replacing bonecp with a different connection pool, and read the API of bonecp to see if they actually implemented the parameter (you might even have to read the code to see if they did that)