# Context datasource settings don't get picked up

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, datasource, jooq

**Goal** 
I am creating a REST webservice (with RESTEasy), and I thought it would be nice if I didn't manage the connection pool but I let Tomcat do that. So I have added a resource in the META-INF/context.xml

**Problem**
I am seeing a lot of connections made on the MySQL server, but I have configured that only 2 as total are allowed. I don't know why, but my settings don't get picked up about the nr of connections etc.

**Context.xml**

```
<Context>
    <!-- DataSource management from tomcat (reference created in web.xml) -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/Taalmaatjes-db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="2" maxIdle="2"
              initialSize="1" maxWaitMillis="10000"
              username="root" password="rootie"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taalmaatjes"
              removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
              removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="5"
              singleton="false" defaultAutoCommit="false" rollbackOnReturn="true" />
</Context>
```

The settings maxTotal, maxIdle, initialSize, maxWaitMillis don't seem to get picked up. Using the commando 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' and connecting to my application 39 times, I get:

```
3   root    localhost:56576 taalmaatjes Query   0   starting    /* ApplicationName=IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 */ SHOW PROCESSLIST
231 root    localhost:57932 taalmaatjes Sleep   102     
232 root    localhost:57933 taalmaatjes Sleep   102     
233 root    localhost:57934 taalmaatjes Sleep   100     
234 root    localhost:57935 taalmaatjes Sleep   99      
235 root    localhost:57936 taalmaatjes Sleep   99      
236 root    localhost:57937 taalmaatjes Sleep   99      
237 root    localhost:57938 taalmaatjes Sleep   99      
238 root    localhost:57939 taalmaatjes Sleep   98      
239 root    localhost:57940 taalmaatjes Sleep   98      
240 root    localhost:57941 taalmaatjes Sleep   98      
241 root    localhost:57942 taalmaatjes Sleep   98      
242 root    localhost:57943 taalmaatjes Sleep   98      
243 root    localhost:57944 taalmaatjes Sleep   98      
244 root    localhost:57945 taalmaatjes Sleep   97      
245 root    localhost:57950 taalmaatjes Sleep   93      
246 root    localhost:57951 taalmaatjes Sleep   93      
247 root    localhost:57952 taalmaatjes Sleep   93      
248 root    localhost:57953 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
249 root    localhost:57954 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
250 root    localhost:57955 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
251 root    localhost:57956 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
252 root    localhost:57957 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
253 root    localhost:57958 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
254 root    localhost:57959 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
255 root    localhost:57960 taalmaatjes Sleep   92      
256 root    localhost:57961 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
257 root    localhost:57962 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
258 root    localhost:57963 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
259 root    localhost:57964 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
260 root    localhost:57965 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
261 root    localhost:57966 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
262 root    localhost:57967 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
263 root    localhost:57968 taalmaatjes Sleep   91      
264 root    localhost:57969 taalmaatjes Sleep   90      
265 root    localhost:57970 taalmaatjes Sleep   90      
266 root    localhost:57971 taalmaatjes Sleep   90      
267 root    localhost:57972 taalmaatjes Sleep   90      
268 root    localhost:57974 taalmaatjes Sleep   90      
269 root    localhost:57975 taalmaatjes Sleep   90
```

**Call to get DataSource in the code**

Here an example which is placed inside a method I can call that does this:

```
@GET
public StringValueObject getVersion() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    DataSource dataSource1 = (DataSource) ((javax.naming.Context) new InitialContext()
            .lookup("java:comp/env"))
            .lookup("jdbc/Taalmaatjes-db");
    dataSource1.getConnection().close();
    return new StringValueObject("v0.1-unsecured");
}
```

Note that after calling this getVersion for 20 times, I have 20 connections still showing with SHOW PROCESSLIST.

**Maybe useful details**
I am using jOOQ as my ORM with a MySQL database. It runs on a tomcat.
I also tried adding factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" because that was mentioned in [Why does my Tomcat only open 8 JDBC connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879706/why-does-my-tomcat-only-open-8-jdbc-connections/30879793). However, it also didn't work.

**My knowledge**
I am really new to this JBNI, JDBC stuff. I know too little and that is why I am here, to learn! I thought I was using Tomcat JBNI, but when I used the setting removeAbandoned="true" it gave the error that this setting doesn't exist and I should use removeAbandonedOnBorrow. So apparently I am using Apache JBDC? Dont really know the difference, since I am just trying to get tomcat to handle my connection pooling. Seemed smart to leave that to another library.

Comment: Please provide code where you use this database connection.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Added small piece of code. I don't know how helpful this really is. Al I am doing is passing it to a jOOQ Dao object, which executes some queries on it. I close it afterwards.

Comment: So you never close the connection, right? That's the issue. Note that **you must ALWAYS call `Connection#close`**. Connection objects from a datasource (connection pool) will go into sleep state (or similar) rather than closing the physical database connection.

Comment: It is really hard to post good chunks of code in these posts without making it unreadable. The basics is that with Guice I am MethodIntercepting all my API-calls, which initializes the datasource for me. After the method call (Which could be anything, for example loging stuff as stated as example). After the method executing, it calls connection.close(). Little bit hard to show here, but I do close it.

Comment: Are you sure you're closing the database connections and that you only have a single application running at the time?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Created a new example which I tested and clearly shows I am closing (that part is copy paste from my code), which still leaves open the connections.

Comment: Also, yeah I am running a single tomcat instance, deploying my artifcat using IntelliJ.

Comment: Looks like every time you're executing `DataSource dataSource1 = (DataSource) ((javax.naming.Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("jdbc/Taalmaatjes-db");` it is creating a new instance of your datasource rather than obtaining it from the pool.

Comment: And I think the issue is here. Your `Resource` configuration has this property: `singleton="false"`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that is correct. If I create dataSource1 and dataSource2, they are not equal. This is because I have singleton="false". That doesn't explain creating more than maxIdle-setting connections right?

Comment: Just have a single datasource. Also, remove all configurations starting with `remove`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Suppose we scale it up and I connect 100times at the same time, retrieving the same DataSource. If I execute multiple select queries, won't other sessions need to wait for the other queries to finish? I thought, in large projects, you want more datasources.

Comment: Rather than wanting more datasources, you will need more connections. Instead of using 2, use a bigger number like 10 or 20. For more scaling, I'd suggest to not increase the database connection number, instead to scale horizontally.

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom! Learned something new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've configured your datasource resource to be not singleton, here:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/Taalmaatjes-db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal="2" maxIdle="2"
    initialSize="1" maxWaitMillis="10000"
    username="root" password="rootie"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taalmaatjes"
    removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" 
    removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="5"
    <!-- here -->
    singleton="false" defaultAutoCommit="false" rollbackOnReturn="true" />
```

Remove it and try again.